# SQL - View which duplicates values for missing entries

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, view

I need to create a view, which would propagate missing values by creating duplicates. Here is an example:

With such table:

```
NR|Description|FK  
0 |Text1      |0  
0 |Text2      |1  
0 |Text4      |2
1 |Text3      |0
```

Create such view:

```
NR|Description|FK  
0 |Text1      |0  
0 |Text2      |1  
0 |Text4      |2  
1 |Text3      |0   
1 |Text3      |1 
1 |Text3      |2
```

The original table will always have at least one entry with specific NR column and column FK valued 0. So in short, if there is a row with unique NR and column FK with value 0 and there is no row with FK valued 1 then create one based on the row with FK value 0

**Edit:**
There can be more than one unique FK value

Answer (score 1):

This should do it

```
declare @T table (NR int, Description varchar(10), FK int);
insert into @T values   
       (0, 'Text1', 0)  
     , (0, 'Text2', 1) 
     , (1, 'Text3', 0);
select t1.NR, t1.Description, t1.FK
from @T t1 
union 
select t1.NR, t1.Description, 1
from @T t1 
left join @T t2 
  on t2.NR = t1.NR 
 and t1.FK = 0 
 and t2.fk = 1 
where t2.NR is null;
```

Comment: Partially this solution works for me. If after tweaking it it will work out I will submit this answer

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
SELECT [NR], [Description], newtbl2.[FK] FROM (

SELECT [NR], [Description], newtbl.[FK] FROM [dbo].[myTable] oldtbl 
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select [NR], [Description], 1 as [FK]) newtbl ON newtbl.[FK] = oldtbl.[FK] 

) joined
LEFT OUTER JOIN (select [NR], [Description], 0 as [FK]) newtbl2 ON newtbl2.[FK] = joined.[FK]
```

What's happening here is: First, I'm left joining a duplicate table with 1 as the `FK` to the original table. That way if there are no rows with 1 as the `FK`, it will create one, if there are a row, it will just join on that row - giving you the same `NR` and `Description`.

Next, I'm joining an additional table with 0 as the `FK`. Basically the same as the first step, but with 0 instead of 1.

The aliasing may need some work, but in principal, this approach should work.

Comment: Thanks, will try it out, if it will help me to get the end result I will mark this as useful